# Sending RPi data over network

Tags: gpio, networking, relay

I have 3 Pi's on a network that need to scan one GPIO on each, and if that GPIO changes, broadcast to the other two so they can trigger another GPIO as an output to trip a local relay.  HELP??

Comment: There need to be more supporting details such as... what  programming language are you using... code snippets that work or don't work... whether you are sending UDP or TCP packets over the network... and what "scan a GPIO" means...  As presented, this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Because of a lack of details, I'm going to give you some pseudo-code that should get you pointed in the right direction...

I'm going to assume you can make system calls and that you have netcat installed (comes installed by default with Raspbian).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Notifier script to send notifications of state changes written in
# bash pseudo-code.

# your code that watches for interrupts on a given GPIO pin

# An iterrupt has been triggered, send notification
notification="your message"    # note: due to the nature of netcat, you're only going to be able to send single-line messages
notifyees="192.168.1.100 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.120"   # a string of space-separated IP addresses for RPi's that need to be aware of the GPIO state change
notificationPort=8081    # should be the same in both scripts
# send notification to each notifyee
for notifyee in $notifyees
do
    echo $notification | nc $notifyee $notificationPort
done

# congratulations, you've communicated the change in GPIO state to all notifyees
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Notifyee script to receive notifications of state changes written in
# bash pseudo-code.

notificationPort=8081    # should be the same in both scripts

# start an infinite loop so that we can listen for multiple messages
while :
do
    # listen for message on network
    stateChange=$(nc -l $notificationPort)

    # We received a message, now process that message
    # for the sake of security, you may want to implement message signing
    #   with gpg to ensure that only valid messages are processed
    case "$stateChange" in
        # state option)
            # code to run for state option
            ;;
        *)
            # code to run if state not matched
            ;;
    esac
done
```